# Rails: return error messages with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

My rails app serves as API for my android app.
I'm wondering when the request encounters any problem, is there a way to detect which error it is on the server side and return with a specific code?

For example, in my `users_controller.rb`,

```
if @user.save
  respond_with(@user)
else  
  render json: {errors: @user.errors.full_messages}
end
```

The output looks like:

```
{"errors":["Username can't be blank","Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)","Email has already been taken"]}
```

How can I check whether it is because of an error of email or an error of password in the controller? Thanks!

Comment: that's tagged android because ...

Comment: My fault. Thanks, njzk2 and @Tomdarkness .

Answer (score -3, accepted):

- go to rails console
- type: u = User.new
- type: u.valid?
- type: u.errors

Examine the result. You should be able to figure it out.

Alternatively read the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html

Hint: errors is just an OrderedHash object with some additional convenience methods, like full_messages. It has all the information that you are looking for, just not in full_messages.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I'm a newbie in software development. BTW, after I use `u.errors.messages.has_key?(:email)` to check whether there is an error related to email, then I check whether `u.errors.messages[:email]` includes the standard error msg "can't be blank" or "is invalid" that I tested before one by one?

Comment: Yes as far as I know you have to check for the actual message string. The error is meant to be shown to a user not to be dynamically processed by automatized code. PS: Please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it, thanks.

Comment: What if rails changes its error msg? I need to rewrite my code to match it?

Comment: Yes. Why exactly do you need to parse the messages though? Can't you just display them to the user? Would help if you explain what you are doing, then I might be able to help more.

Comment: I'm writing the API to my Android app, so I need to return the specific error code, which looks like: {"error_code": 200001; "error": "email is in use"}

Comment: Well, you can figure out on which fields the errors are on, but for what exactly the error is you can only get the string. I don't see the problem though, just display the error string to the user in the Android app. I don't see why you would need a different error code depending on what the error is, in the end you will just display the error string to the user anyway.

Comment: Because sometimes there are multiple errors, and our android guy needs to reproduce the error message. If I pass the full error messages to the android guy, he will have to do the string comparison by himself, so I guess I should pass him a specific error code. Maybe there are better ways out there, I'm just too green to see them...

Comment: Why does he need to reproduce it? Just display it directly to the user... I don't see the problem. What does it help your Android guy if he knows exactly what is wrong with the field? He can't just change it himself without letting the user know, or if that's what you want just do it server-side then. And if you need translations you can do this server-side also. I really don't see the problem.

Comment: For example, one of the error message is "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)", and the Android guy may reproduce it as "Please choose a longer password."

Comment: Then just change the error message to be that, instead of the standard message? If you want the error to be different for Android as opposed to the web interface, then use a different locale for Android clients.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the errors of a specific field by using @user.errors[:field_name]. A quick way to check if anything is invalid with a specific field is to use `.any?`

i.e

```
@user.errors[:field_name].any?
```

Will return true if there is any kind of problem with this field.